# How create a new columns based on mutliple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas datframe df with columns Speed, Fall Rate and Hit Rate.

I want to classify these 3 columns them  into classes( create new class Columns for each ) based on the condition described below.If the values are fall in the comes in that range .

```
Speed    Speed Class Fall Rate  Fall Class  Hit rate       Hit Class
<=38        Green    <2.5       Green       0 <=0.5        Green
>39 <= 74   Green  >2.5 <=7.6   Green     >0.5 <=1.2       Green
>74 <=117   Yellow    >7.6 <=10 Yellow      >1.2 <=1.4     Yellow
>117        Red     >10         Red      >1.4              Red
```

Sample Input

[image]

Expected  Output

[image]

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: Use `np.select`, tons of questions similar :)

Comment: @jezrael,any easy way to do